# Does $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right]\le \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{\mathbb{E}[X+Y]}$ hold?

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, expected-value

> Assume that two random variables $X$ and $Y$ satisfy $X\ge 0$, $Y\ge0$ and $X+Y\ge 1$. Does it hold that $$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right]\le \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{\mathbb{E}[X+Y]},$$ whereby $\mathbb{E}[\cdot]$ denotes the expected value?

Jensen's inequality may be helpful, but I don't know how to apply it here.

I want to add the additional condition that X increases if X+Y increases.

Comment: I want to add the additional condition that X increases if X+Y increases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Both directions of the inequality are possible:

Case A: $X=1$ or $4$ with equal probability and independently $Y=1$ or $2$ with equal probability

- $E\big[\frac{X}{X+Y}\big] = 0.575 < 0.625 = \frac{E[X]}{E[X+Y]}$

Case B: $X=1$ or $2$ with equal probability and independently $Y=1$ or $4$ with equal probability

- $E\big[\frac{X}{X+Y}\big] = 0.425 > 0.375 = \frac{E[X]}{E[X+Y]}$

---

With further thought, finding examples having two directions for the inequality is trivial whenever you do not start with equality (you do not need independence); all you have to do is swap $X$ and $Y$, since both $E\big[\frac{X}{X+Y}\big]+E\big[\frac{Y}{Y+X}\big]=1$ and
$\frac{E[X]}{E[X+Y]} +\frac{E[Y]}{E[Y+X]}=1$, so
$$E\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right] < \frac{E[X]}{E[X+Y]} \iff E\left[\frac{Y}{Y+X}\right]> \frac{E[Y]}{E[Y+X]}.$$

Clearly $E\big[\frac{X}{X+Y}\big]$ and $\frac{E[X]}{E[X+Y]}$ are each between $0$ and $1$ so the difference between them is between $-1$ and $+1$.  They can approach these bounds, for example with $P\big((X,Y)=(n^4,1)\big)=\frac1n$ and $P\big((X,Y)=(1,n^2)\big)=1-\frac1n$  which for large $n$ gives $E\big[\frac{X}{X+Y}\big] \approx \frac1n +\frac1{n^2}$ approaching $0$ and $\frac{E[X]}{E[X+Y]} \approx 1-\frac1n +\frac2{n^2}$ approaching $1$.

Comment: What if X is an increasing function of (X+Y)?

Comment: @John $X$ is a random variable so I am not sure what you mean by "$X$ is an increasing function of $(X+Y)$".  In any case $0 \le Y$ so $X \le X+Y$ and $0 \le \frac{X}{X+Y}\le 1$.

Comment: I meant X increases when Z:=X+Y increases.

Comment: @John Take for example $(X,Y,Z)=(1,1,2)$ or $=(6,2,8)$, with equal probability:  $E\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right] = 0.625 < 0.7 = \frac{E[X]}{E[X+Y]}$.  So taking for example $(X,Y,Z)=(1,1,2)$ or $=(2,6,8)$, with equal probability:  $E\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right] = 0.375 > 0.3 = \frac{E[X]}{E[X+Y]}$. In both examples $X$ and $Z$ (and $Y$) increase together, and it is another illustration of how you can reverse the inequality by swapping $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

If $X=1$ then inequality becomes $E(\frac 1 Z) \leq \frac 1 {EZ}$ where $Z=1+Y$. Jensen's inequality applied to $\phi (x)=\frac  1x$ (which is strictly convex on $(0,\infty)$ shows that  $E(\frac 1 Z) > \frac 1 {EZ}$ as long as $Y$ is non-constant.